# Delete last word (Ctrl-W): Make bash shell behave like vim command line

Tags: command-line, bash, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Among the many useful keyboard shortcuts available in the bash shell, there is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> to delete the word to the left of the cursor. Let's suppose my command line looks like the following:

```
cp some-file /foo/bar/baz/copy
```

Now I'd expect to be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> and end up with the following:

```
cp some-file /foo/bar/baz/
```

In Vim's command line it actually works this way: Only alphanumeric characters are treated as "word", whereas special characters (like `/`) serve as delimiters marking the start of a new "word".

But unfortunately it doesn't work like that in all shells I've used so far. Only spaces will delimit a "word", so pressing the shortcut with the command line shown above will give me:

```
cp some-file
```

Is there a way to make Bash behave like Vim? Some configuration I can put into my `.bashrc`?

Comment: See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-to-delete-part-of-a-path-in-an-interactive-shell) and pay attention to [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30480/55482). For some reason it is not upvoted, but it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Vim, all editors behave that way (including emacs), they treat non-word characters as delimiters. Anyway, the behavior you are talking about is controlled by `readline` and its manual lists quite a few commands you can assign shortcuts to. I am pasting a few relevant ones here but I recommend you read `man readline` for more info:

```
   backward-word (M-b)
          Move  back  to  the  start  of the current or previous word.  Words 
          are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).

   kill-line (C-k)
          Kill the text from point to the end of the line.
   kill-word (M-d)
          Kill from point the end of  the  current  word,  or  if  between
          words,  to  the  end  of the next word.  Word boundaries are the
          same as those used by forward-word.
   backward-kill-word (M-Rubout)
          Kill the word behind point.  Word boundaries  are  the  same  as
          those used by backward-word.
   unix-word-rubout (C-w)
          Kill  the  word behind point, using white space as a word bound‐
          ary.  The killed text is saved on the kill-ring.
   unix-filename-rubout
          Kill the word behind point, using  white  space  and  the  slash
          character  as  the word boundaries.  The killed text is saved on
          the kill-ring.
```

So, the one you want is `backward-kill-word`, which uses non alphanumeric characters as word boundaries. By default, it is assigned to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> but you can change that by using either the global `/etc/inputrc` if you want them to apply to all users or (better) your own local `$HOME/.inputrc`.

As far as I can tell, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> seems to be reserved and you can't use that one but you can choose another shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for example. Create a `$HOME/.inputrc` file if it doesn't exist and add this line to it:

```
Control-J: backward-kill-word
```

That should be enough for most modern terminal emulators. However, some older terminals use different codes. If you're using `xterm`, for example, the line above should be written as:

```
C-J: backward-kill-word
```

Comment: Very thorough explanation, thanks! In the end, I chose to use this approach.

Comment: `\C-w` is not reserved.  Just run `bind 'set bind-tty-special-chars off'` to turn off the `bind-tty-special-chars` setting that causes readline to re-read and re-bind the terminal's special characters (in this case the `werase` character) every time that a new line is to be input.

Comment: @JdeBP ah, OK, thanks. I just saw that it was explicitly mentioned in the `man` page and that I could not overwrite the setting in my `.inputrc`.

Comment: Please note that: backward-kill-word does not work like in vim... foo/bar will be deleted in 3 ctrl+w, ie foo/bar -> foo/ -> foo -> deleted, where in the shell, foo/bar -> foo/ -> deleted

Answer (score 5):

You can enable readline's (and thus bash's) so called "vi mode" by putting the following lines in `~/.inputrc` and starting a new shell:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
```

But you will notice that `<C-w>` works the same as with the default Emacs mode: words are space-delimited. You can do `dT/` or similar commands, though. It's still an emulation, not the real deal. The available mappings are listed in readline's manual:

```
$ man readline
/VI
```

See also [this page on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal).

But I don't think readline's vi mode is that useful, if you often find yourself in need of seriously editing your command line… why not use Vim *for real*?

```
<C-x><C-e>
```

Comment: Wow that last shortcut to invoke my editor is great! Although if my command line reaches that level of complexity, I'll rather stick it in a shell script. Still, good to know!

Answer (score 1):

There are two options that I know of, though neither directly does what you ask.

1. set bash to use vi mode, where the prompt then behaves like a line in vi.  The command is `set -o vi`.  Ref: [BASH Help - A Bash Tutorial](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php)
2. Add vi key maps to your current shell prompt.  Ref: [StackOverflow: What does set key map vi do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002356/what-does-set-keymap-vi-do)